# Android: extract android:pathData from vector xml

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to create a custom image view to crop image according vector that accept so in order i create a simple vector xml :

**simple_vector.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="400px"
    android:height="400px"
    android:viewportHeight="400.0"
    android:viewportWidth="400.0" >
        <path
            android:fillColor="#0000FF"
            android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:strokeWidth="4"
            android:pathData="M100,100 L 300,100 L 200,300z" />
</vector>
```

[image]

I create a class that extended from `AppCompatImageView`:
This is my initview method:

```
private void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.ShapedView, 0, 0);
    model_crop = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ShapedView_model_crop);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getDrawable()).getBitmap();

}
```

So i have `model_crop`.Now i want to extract `pathData` from vector xml to create `Path`.How can i extract pathData from model_crop ?

Comment: you cannot with `VectorDrawable`, use [VectorMaster](https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster) instead

Comment: Thank you dude . I don't want to add outer library to creating custom cropped image view...@pskink

Comment: so you cannot access `pathData` - or you parse your xml files with your own parser: i think using `VectorMaster` is much easier

Comment: I decided to use string like this in custom view `<attr name="model_crop_string" format="string"/>` to give directly path as string to view @pskink

Comment: good, but why to make your life harder if you have xml files? i think that with `VectorMaster` you could get even the `Path` directly

Comment: I do not know why but i do not have a good feeling when i want to add outer library to project specially when it is not very important section of project and it can be done with a simple string instead of using outer library @pskink

Comment: so make your own xml parser: its 30 minutes work

Comment: I never made xml parser ! do you have any reference to make xml parser?@pskink

Comment: I think it is good reference https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers @pskink

Comment: https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster/blob/master/vectormaster/src/main/java/com/sdsmdg/harjot/vectormaster/VectorMasterDrawable.java#L98 - here they got `pathData`: https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster/blob/master/vectormaster/src/main/java/com/sdsmdg/harjot/vectormaster/VectorMasterDrawable.java#L135

Comment: You know , you are a good friend dude. Thanks bro @pskink

Comment: sure, your welcome: the most simple parser is here: https://gist.github.com/pskink/0fb50212b5f03b887654e80b989f9505#file-v-java-L48